# Calling nest API from Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am trying to call an nest api to get room temperature using C code in Arduino.

When I call the api using postman, I get perfect response:

[image]

However when I write the code to get the temperature data, I get the following response:

**request sent
The request is HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.**

Here is my code, can anyone help me what's wrong with my request:

```
const char* ssid = "linksys";
const char* password = "XXXXX";

const char* host = "firebase-apiserver07-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com"; // "developer-api.nest.com"; // "api.github.com";
const int httpsPort = 9553; //443 9553;
String url = "";


.......
.......
.......

 if (!client.connect(host, httpsPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  } else {
        client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "Authorization: Bearer c.SbsgvTBcsJREMOVED_CODE_FOR_SECURITY_REASON\r\n" +
               "Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n"
               );

        Serial.println("request sent");
  }
```

Thanks,

Shab

Comment: 1) Don't post images of text. 2) Arduino is not C and not exactly C++.

Comment: Probably because you need a secure connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a 400, you should check that the URL is actually set to `/`. Your code doesn't have the value of the `url` variable shown.

Comment: Thanks Femi for the promot response and sorry that I missed that part of the code. url is set to empty string because when I put "/" I get no response. Not even bad request.

Comment: @user1952378 well, empty string is very definitely wrong. It causes you to output something that isn't a syntactically valid HTTP request... which would explain the "bad request" :)

Comment: @hobbs, I see, but why putting '/' doesn't even get any response?

Comment: Not quite familiar with the Nest API, but you should check the path in Postman, and make sure you use that for URL: an empty response typically means you didn't ask for anything in particular, or possibly you got a redirect. Check if there are response headers that indicate you were redirected to a different url.

Answer (score 0):

I figured in my case there was a delay in receiving the response. I just had to wait to get the response. And for sure url has to be "/"

String url = "/"

Thanks,
Shab